# Using PHP to change pages content

Tags: php, html

I have a few pages, PAGE 1 is an input form that allows accesed users to change PAGE 2/3 etc.... I am hoping to use PHP to do this but im not too PHP savvy.

### Scenario

Page 1 has two drop down menus that are made in HTML (master page) the first has the persons name "Mike" & "Jim" and the second contains a score from 0 to 10. I want that if i select mike and 7 and then click submit, it will update page 2 (mikes page) and display "Mike" & "7" and then if i click "Jim" & "3" it will update jims page to display Jim and 3

How will i most efficiently go about doing this? preferably simple PHP if its possible.

All these pages + scripts will be on a server & i know jscript only is client side meaning it cannot change another page.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to store the information somewhere, maybe in the php $_SESSION or a database. Javascript can be used for browser storage and cookies, therefore you can specify something in one page and carry it to other pages, as long as the cookies exist.

Comment: If i understood that correctly, simple HTML Forms will do that. POST or GET are your friends in that case.

Comment: Conditional statements will take care of that.

Comment: @NikosMargaritis ive never worked with sessions before ill do some quick research to see if its what ill need. Did some research and it seems somewhat perfect but does a session need to last forever? or does the session only exist while changes are being made i.e. the form page is open. Can i store the session variables in a different file and use a php script to change them depending on the input from the html drop down form?

Comment: If you want to store stuff forever you will make a database. The session can either last as long as the page is open or for an amount of minutes that you specify (but that doesn't mean that you will specify a session for months and you will be ok with it).

Comment: @Nikos Margaritis session will last until the browser is closed or its data is cleared or session is destroyed, depending on browser to browsers. the thing you mentioned above "** The session can either last as long as the page is open or for an amount of minutes that you specify**" are valid for cookies, not for sessions..

Comment: @choxx Not for the session to which I was referring. You can specify a session id to be stored as a cookie. Then by the use of that session id in the cookie you retrieve the session in the PHP server. Therefore, the "quote" that you mentioned applies. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php and I quote from the PHP manual "Although HTTP cookie has some problems, cookie is preferred way to manage session ID. Use only cookies for session ID management when it is possible. Most applications should use cookie for session ID."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by creating sessions. for example, there i have taken 2 pages and sending data from input field of one page to another

page1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start(); //this must be the first line in php page
    $_SESSION['variable']=$_POST['anything']; // this will save value from input tag in form in session.
header( "Location: page2.php" );
    ?>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Session</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Welcome to page 1.
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <form method="post" action="page1.php"> // this will call page2.php on button click
          Type anything
          <input type="text" name="anything" />
          <input type="submit" value="Send value to page 2" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['variable'];
?>
```

Comment: like above you can create many session variables as **$_SESSION['variable']** and use them to share data between pages. let me know if there is any doubt..

Comment: Whenever a button is clicked, it goes to page2. So it will never assign the $_POST['anything'] to the Session... The php part of page1 should be in page2.

Comment: see in page1.php i wrote**$_SESSION['variable']=$_POST['anything'];**. this is creating a session variable in the browser, not in any page. this session's variable can be accessed by any page by **$_SESSION['variable']** this only. as an example i have shown to go to page2.php on button click. it is not necessary to do so. you can do something else useful to you in the same manner by creating session vars.

Comment: yup this will work. There needs to be an `if(isset($_POST['anything']))` around the php part though.

Comment: yes, this will check if something is entered in the input field & then button clicked or without entering any value in the field & then button clicked.. and let me know if that solved your issue or not?

Comment: @choxx
This is GREAT and its helped clear up ALOT of things for me thank you so much just a few things left now.

1: am i able to use an if command to check if the selected input was Mike then you will alter page two else if it was Jim then it will alter page 3 or not alter but send information to?

Comment: yes, you can use if condition to check the value stored in the session var is mike or jim or anything. for example 'if($_SESSION["variable"]=="MIke"){ header( "Location: page2.php" ); }' like that..

Comment: similarly you can check for jim or any other value stored in the session variable... and please click accept answer and vote up so that other may also find this useful..

Comment: @choxx you have helped me so much its unbelievable! i understand now, am i able to add you on some form of social media or something to further discuss some simple questions? dont want to litter this page with small questions. As long as you are okay with it that is =)

Comment: ya, sure,,, catch me [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AbhishekMishraChoxx/posts) on Google+